# Merging 2 lists with linq based on unique Id to avoid duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of products: products and extraProducts
My goal is to merge the 2 lists but avoid duplicates based on the Id only.

**Here is my best attempt:**

```
List<Product> allProductsWithNoDuplicates = new List<Product>();

allProductsWithNoDuplicates.AddRange(products.Where(p => extraProducts.Select(ep => ep.Id).Contains(p.Id)).ToList());
```

However it does not work because it needs to be where NOT Contains.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, create a IComparer class,

```
public class ProductComparer: IComparer 
{
  int IComparer.Compare(object a, object b)
 {
    if(a.Id == b.Id)
      return 0;
    else
     return 1;
 }
}
```

Then use Distinct() after concatenating two lists.

```
allProductsWithNoDuplicates =   products.Concat(extraProducts).Distinct(new ProductComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Instead I implemented IEqualityComparer in my Product model. How would I do the distinct or union this way?

Answer (score 4):

This should help you out - It's a console app...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listA = new List<Product>();

            var listB = new List<Product>();

            listA.Add(new Product() {Id = 1, Name = "Hair Curling Tongs"});
            listA.Add(new Product() {Id = 2, Name = "Toys"});
            listA.Add(new Product() {Id = 3, Name = "Coffee"});

            listB.Add(new Product() {Id = 3, Name = "Dress"});
            listB.Add(new Product() {Id = 4, Name = "Handbag"});

            var results = listA.Union(listB).Distinct(new EqualityComparer()).ToList();

            foreach(var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ----- {1}", result.Id, result.Name);
            }

            // TODO: Implement Functionality Here

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    class Product{
        public int Id{get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }

    class EqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<Product> {

        public bool Equals(Product p1, Product p2) {
            return p1.Id == p2.Id;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Product p){
            return p.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

This looks like a useful link for you as well - http://www.elevenwinds.com/blog/linq-distinctby-with-lambda-expression-parameter/

Comment: What is I made it so my Product model already implements IEqualityComparer?

Comment: Odd design choice - think single responsibility...

You could just pass a new instance of product in place of the EqualityComparer, but that is hacky... I'd look again at your design.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Union` statement with an `IEqualityComparer`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

To use Union, you can do the following:

```
List<Product> myUniqueProducts = products.Union(extraProducts, new ProductEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

It also gives examples in the documentation at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I am aware I can do this, but since Id is the only thing I am using to compare is there another way? I just feel like IEqualityComparer is overkill in this case.

Comment: I understand that making a class for this feels a bit too much, a simple function would be enough, But using a `Where` combined with `Contains` makes the complexity larger and makes the algorithm slower.

Comment: So I decided to implement IEqualityComparer on my Product object just like the documentation you gave me. This is because I realized I need to check more than just the Id to compare them. Now that this is done how do I use Union?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `Union` is the best here. And there is `Distinct` function you can use:

```
var allProductsWithNoDuplicates = products.Union(extraProducts).DistinctBy(x => x.Id);
```

This should union you two lists in one without without same elements by **Id** property.